# Why is "feminism" good but "racism" and other "-isms" bad?

Tags: etymology, nouns, connotation, suffixes

Feminism is generally seen as a good thing.  It means something or other about achieving equality of the sexes; of treating people of different sexes the same or as well as each other.

Racism is generally seen as a bad thing. It means something or other about not achieving equality between people of different races; of treating people of different races differently and badly.

Why is there this difference between *-isms*?  Where did it come from?

Comment: Depending on who you're talking to, *radicalism*, for example, may have positive, neutral, or negative associations.

Comment: _Altruism_ was only conceived of as bad by W. C. Fields, I believe.

Comment: Learned long ago "prism" is the most beautiful -ism.

Comment: '-ism' doesn't mean 'a bad thing about ...'. It means 'a thing about ...'. The difference in connotation comes from the subject an usage. 'Racism' is about treating people badly because of race. 'Feminism' is about giving more rights to women. The suffix isn't good or bad, it's the entire concept. Don't get stuck on the suffix.

Comment: Interestingly ["masculism"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/masculism) includes in its definition "Support for patriarchy / male domination of women; opposition to equality for women; anti-feminism" 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/-ism?q=-ism) defines the suffix **-ism** as

> 1. denoting an action or its result:
>      baptism
>      exorcism
>
>    denoting a state or quality:
>      barbarism
> 2. denoting a system, principle, or ideological movement:
>      Anglicanism
>      feminism
>      hedonism
>
>    denoting a basis for prejudice or discrimination:
>      racism
> 3. denoting a peculiarity in language:
>      colloquialism
>      Canadianism
> 4. denoting a pathological condition:
>      alcoholism

There is no inherent *good* or *bad* about these uses (except possibly the disease definition).

The source, according to ODO is

> from French -isme, via Latin from Greek -ismos, -isma

Comment: So definition 2 is contradictory?  Because SPONKISM could be discrimination against sponks, or belonging to the SPONK movement?  There's no way to guess if FATISM is promoting fat acceptance or is  fat discrimination without looking up a definition of fatism?

Comment: @DanBeale: You are correct. There isn't an easy way to determine which is accurate without looking it up (or using context.)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything about the -ism suffix that is inherently ethical or unethical. The moral aspect relates to the other side of the word. In terms of "feminism"; the immoral variant would be "sexism".

But most -isms are just classifications of people or ways of thought. Something like "communism" or "socialism" isn't inherently good *or* bad. It's just a political affiliation.