# Apolitical synonym for "racism"

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

Until recently I assumed that “racism” simply meant a belief that there are innate and meaningful differences between races.

I thought that the common practice of using "racism" as a stand-in for hatred against other races, a discriminatory/segregationist political agenda, etc. was mainly a colloquial simplification meant to ease/influence public discourse. I was surprised to find that indeed, [Wikipedia defines racism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racism) as **primarily** related to certain political stances (with the belief in innate differences between races and ethnicities only listed as common justification). Whether this was always the case or is just an example of a colloqualism becoming a norm, I cannot say.

Still, now I am left to wonder: How can one refer to the belief that there are innate and meaningful differences between races - **independently** of any political stance?

Examples of using such a word:

- My recent studies indicate that racial provenance is a good predictor for performance on tasks A and B. I am convinced of the quality of my research but not apt or willing to make political recommendations based on it. I do not believe that races are equal in their capabilities, I am a proponent of **“Y”**. I am a **“y”**-ist.
- I believe that my racial group is innately less capable than other races at C, but I do not think this is a compelling argument to deny us a fair chance at C. I do not believe that all races are equal, I believe in **“Y”**. I am a **“y”**-ist.

Comment: It is my understanding that the suffix '-ism' always indicates a political or religious belief. Therefore I'm not surprised that this applies to racism. Please can you provide a sample sentence with a blank where the desired word would go. The extra context will show how you wish to use it. Thanks.

Comment: A similar question is here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115221/more-precise-word-or-phrase-for-neutral-connotation-of-racism?rq=1 - and another here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142750/why-is-feminism-good-but-racism-and-other-isms-bad?rq=1

Comment: @chasly The magnetism movement failed to attract many followers.

Comment: '[Racial] diversity' is unmarked. It was suggested (then deleted) in one of the threads chasly links to.

Comment: @chasly Thank you for the links - but one of the questions is not really related to what I am asking. The second (first) one is indeed almost a duplicate, but has no satisfactory answer. What is the adjective then, racialitist?

Comment: It is often the case in English that certain words have both a political/emotional meaning and an apolitical/unemotional one.  The language does not naturally develop separate terms for the two contexts, since any word is apt to gain associations as it's used.  In the case of "racism" there have been so many attempts, over the centuries, to define a "scientific" (yet ultimately bogus) basis for racism that most of the possible terms have been sullied beyond reasonable repair.

Comment: Note that the scientific aspect is only an example of who could use such a word. The defining quality of the word I am looking for is not “scientific”, but “apolitical”.

Comment: I can't see how judgements on variations in human ability which are based on a concept like "race" can be _apolitical_. If someone is claiming that one racial group is more capable than another in some way, they've made a huge political statement.

Comment: @TheChymera Then how about "identification of physical traits".   I suppose you could call it "traitism" if you wished.

Comment: The term 'geneticism' cries out to be used. To use it, however, you'd have to rewrite and quite possibly rethink such expressions as are included in your examples. Hurry, though, you haven't much time before political and cultural systems overwhelm the current general neutrality of such terms as 'geneticism' and 'geneticist'.

Comment: If you don't mind a neologism which, although likely to be widely understood without further explanation or definition, has its own attendant problems (that is, 1. it's likely to arouse visceral dislike in language fascists, and 2. it's a tongue-twister), you could use 'subspeciesist'. Perhaps I should make this an answer but I'm understandably reluctant about being that closely associated with the suggestion.

Comment: @Margana Races tend to be geographically restricted. Races having a large number of people living at relatively high altitudes win disproportionately more medals in say long-distance races. Maritime races tend to have more skillful yachtspersons. Some Japanese studies once provided evidence that the Caucasian brain had, in general, greater potential to make scientific breakthroughs than the Japanese.

Comment: Let's just take the example of lactose tolerance, which is more prevalent among descendants of early herding peoples -- Scandanavians and some Africans.  The ability to digest lactose in adulthood arose among these peoples quite recently -- maybe 4,000 years ago.  What would the readers of this question call someone who acknowledged this fact?  (The distribution of lactose tolerance is not controversial.)   Not a racist, but what?  I think the wording of the OP could be improved.

Comment: @ab2 - There is an interesting story that lactose intolerance on the part of Native Americans caused them to attack an early Nordic settlement in North America, because they were fed milk at a feast and then thought they'd been poisoned when they all developed stomach distress.  Had this not happened it's arguable that North America would be speaking Norwegian today.

Comment: I haven't carefully picked apart all the threads in this complex weave.  However, I have a term to propose to the OP: **race awareness**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Y** and **y**, you may use the words **racialism** and **racialist**.

*"Racialism" is an emphasis on race or racial considerations, as in determining policy or interpreting events. It is the belief that human species are naturally divided into distinct biological categories called "races."*

In this Huffington Post article titled  ["Racism and Racialism Are Different"](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/peter-h-schuck/racism-and-racialism-are-_b_6368010.html), it is written that:

> Racialism is rational, morally neutral, and inevitable in a society
>   with our history of slavery, discrimination, and white-black social
>   differences in so many areas.

Comment: The Huffington Post notwithstanding, dictionaries give "racism" as a synonym for "racialism."  This is certainly the sole meaning for "racialism" from the 1920s to at least the 1940s, and even today writers (like Peter Schuck in THP) who wish to distinguish the two take pains to point out their special usage.  In these instances, racialism is usually defined to encompass social, cultural, and economic factors  associated with skin color.  These are not the "innate" characteristics that the OP is concerned with.

Comment: @deadrat - Historically, the view that race is a natural kind was associated to a belief in racial essences, a view K.A. Appiah calls racialism. It is the view that “we could divide human beings into a small number of groups, called ‘races’, in such a way that members of these groups shared certain fundamental, heritable, physical, moral, intellectual, and cultural  characteristics  with  one  another  that  they  did  not  share  with members  of  any  other race.” *Source: [Race, Culture, Identity: Misunderstood 
Connections](http://philpapers.org/archive/APPRCI.pdf) by K. Anthony Appiah*.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this.  Historically, there was a view that human physiology was governed by four humors and that things burned because they contained a substance called phlogiston.  What you reply if I asked you for a scientific term for the action of black bile in depression?  Or for a thermodynamic term for the release of phlogiston during an exothermic process?

Comment: @deadrat - I just proposed a word in the context of the question. My intention was not to provide a judgement of any kind on the subject. If had to do it, I would say that "racialism" is a pseudo-scientific theory used to justify racism.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to refer to "the belief that there are innate and meaningful differences between races" is "abyssal ignorance."  In particular, ignorance of the current state of our knowledge of human population genetics. "Race" is tricky to define, and if you use skin color, you end up with as large a genetic variation between races as within them.  You'll have better luck defining race by ancestral geographical origin, but only for making valid statements about correlations within populations, not about individuals.  And geographical origin isn't always a good fit for societal definition of race.  Please forgive me for leaving to you the task of researching the term "human genetic diversity."

It was not always thus.  The Ngram viewer will reveal that the terms "raciology" and "scientific racism" were in vogue in the 1920s, but events in Germany starting in 1933 put a dent in their popularity.  Probably the high point of the scientific endorsement of racial principles came in 1962 with the publication of *The Origin of Races* by Carleton S Coon, a professor of anthropology at the University of Pennsylvania and Harvard University and one-time President of the American Association of Physical Anthropologists.  With the advent of the civil rights movement shortly thereafter in the US, the coupling of political views to the term "racism" became permanent.

Comment: I feel you are questioning the question instead of answering it. I am asking about a word, and you are presenting your political views and understanding of current research to the avail of discrediting the question.

Comment: Along these lines, I read some time back (probably in Scientific American) that the way that human fertility responds to vitamin D (and vitamin D's relationship to sunlight) means that skin color very rapidly adapts (within maybe 100-200 years) to changes in latitude and associated changes in sunlight.  Skin color is one of the least "durable" of racial characteristics.

Comment: I don't think anyone really disagrees that genetic differentiators exist, just that differentiators are by and large meaningless.

Comment: @TheChymera I do not share your view that the answer is a political one. I think both of the statements in your question would be seen as racist in the pejorative sense by large numbers of people. It would be instructive if you were to review the reaction to the work of the  psychologist [Hans Eysenk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Eysenck#Genetics_and_intelligence) in the 1970s. This is a complex matter where the principle you are trying to establish cannot be divorced from politics and regarded as uniquely scientific.

Comment: When 'race' is used synonymously with 'subspecies' ([OED](http://oed.com/): "The subspecies in biology has been variously defined and is frequently regarded as synonymous with ‘race’."), innate morphological features define the 'race'. Such features are meaningful **at least** in the sense that they are empirical and often conspicuously so. Equally, human subspecies ('races') are, or have sometimes been, legitimately defined on the basis of morphological features, which are both innate and empirically meaningful.

Comment: @JEL: Right, but are there morphologies that significantly impact capabilities? The morphological differences between genders are gradually being regarded as having low relevance. What is important is whether a particular individual is capable of performing some required function. Racial differences fall in the same camp.

Comment: @jxh, I think so, but thinking so wonder why you do not. Camouflage coloring springs to mind, and significantly impacts survival capabilities; camouflage is but one of many. Edwin pointed out subtle variations in osmotic oxygen transfer capabillities (adapted to high altitudes), but I'm not sure it's relevant; however, wing length and shape in bird subspecies is another example; many other examples exist. I'm tempted to say that skin color (light in northern latitudes, darker at the equator) is a morphological feature associated with survival capability, but I don't know for sure that's true.

Comment: @JEL: While a trait may affect capability, it does not preclude a particular individual which lacks such trait from also being capable.

Comment: @JEL *Homo sapiens* is currently considered montypic, i.e., we have no subspecies.  Which is one reason why the OP's search is likely futile.

Comment: I concur with your opinion that the OP's search is likely futile. That no human subspecies exist may not be a reason for that, though. See, for example, [Is Homo sapiens polytypic?](https://lesacreduprintemps19.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/woodley-2009-is-homo-sapiens-polytypic-human-taxonomic-diversity-and-its-implications.pdf). In that article's introduction, the point is made that while a majority of surveyed socio-cultural anthropologists agreed that humans are monotypic, a much larger percentage of biologists disagreed. In socio-political contexts, any term for the OP will be shot down.